# Build and Deploy Oracle Forms 10g using Jenkins?

Tags: oracle, jenkins, continuous-integration, oracle10g

Is there a way to build,compile And deploy oracle 10g forms using Jenkins CI Tools ?

Comment: Hello @user6296647. Were you able to integrate Oracle Forms to Jenkins? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As nobody answered (yet), here's what I think - I might be wrong about it, though.

From my point if view,

- you can't build (create) forms unless you use Oracle Forms Builder (or Designer). Once upon a time, when forms were plain text files (such as Oracle Forms 3.0 & its .INP files), you could have tried to write a form "manually", but I don't know anyone who would want to do that - that's why we have a Forms Builder that does all the *dirty* job for us, developers. I don't think that Jenkins is capable of doing that
- compile: that would work, as you can run a *compiler* at the operating system command prompt - if you have a .FMB file, use `frmcmp.exe` to compile it
- deploy: if everything is set up - Forms Services run on the IAS; `formsweb.cfg` file is set, if the compiled .FMX file is in a directory contained in the FORMS_PATH, the form should work. However, if by "deploying" you mean "installing the IAS first and then ...", you're out of luck. IAS setup is not a trivial task at all and I doubt that Jenkins could do that

A conclusion: if you're lucky, 2 out of 3 steps can be done. Otherwise, just one - compilation - works, which is probably not good enough for you.

Comment: Hello @LittleFoot. Got it. Thank you for answering. We will still try if the integration is really possible or not. Thank you.